# Реализация корзины интернет-магазина на Django

Tags: django, cookie, auth

Дабы не замораживать пользователя с регистрацией, от личного кабинета решили отказаться. В следствии чего вариант идентификации пользователя при помощи django.conrib.auth отпадает, но хранить данные о корзине как-то надо.

Решил что при добавлении товара в пустую корзину буду создавать session_key (из django.contrib.sessions.backends.db.SessionStore) и передать его в куки файл пользователю, а данные о товарах в корзине буду хранить в бд.

Так как опыта работы с сессиями Django и куки не много, интересует вопрос: на сколько вышеописанное использование session_key и куки является правильным,и нет ли других способов идентификации незарегистрированного пользователя?

Comment: Насколько помню, это единственный вариант определить конкретного пользователя. Так что юзайте куки, изайте SessionStore https://djbook.ru/rel1.8/topics/http/sessions.html

Comment: а вообще посмотри пакеты на djangopackages.org , наверняка имеется готовое решение для карзины без авторизации

Comment: Есть отличный пример из онлайн-учебника: https://pocoz.gitbooks.io/django-v-primerah/content/glava-7-sozdanie-internet-magazina/sozdanie-korzini.html
Довольно подробно расписана тема создания корзины без регистрации пользователя.